# Directive taking title from the last modal html always

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a code in below way

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('abc.directives', [])
.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ modalTitle }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.modalTitle = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };  
  });
```

and html like

```
<modal title="success" id='successmessage' visible="successmessage">
    <form role="form">
        Action was uccesful
        <span class="clearfix"></span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="closemodal('successmessage');>Ok</button>
    </form>
</modal>    
<modal title="Error" id='errormessage' visible="errormessage">
<form role="form">
    Action was not Succesful
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="closemodal('errormessage');>Ok</button>
</form>
```

All functionality works fine. But in modal header title is always showing as

```
Error
```

i.e. title of last modal windows. Even if i open success window its same case. How do i fix this problem?

Here is the JSfiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/98v0pozz/4/

Comment: Did you make a typo? You have `modal title="Error"` on your success modal also.

Comment: very strange code. Why u need these watches? I.e. scope : {visible : '=visible'} and use ng-show="visible" in template. Same for title.

Comment: Please check code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "id" to modal tags:

```
<modal id="0" title="Login form" visible="showModal">
<modal id="1" title="Login form1" visible="showModal1">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.titles = [];
$scope.toggleModal = function(){
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
    $scope.title = $scope.titles["0"];
};
 $scope.toggleModal1 = function(){
    $scope.showModal1 = !$scope.showModal1;
    $scope.title = $scope.titles["1"];
};
```

In directive:

```
scope.titles[attrs.id] = attrs.title;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the title of success modal as 'Error'.

Try this:

```
<modal title="Success" id='successmessage' visible="successmessage">
    <form role="form">
        Action was uccesful
        <span class="clearfix"></span>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="closemodal('successmessage');>Ok</button>
    </form>
</modal>    
<modal title="Error" id='errormessage' visible="errormessage">
```

Comment: @ Vipul Agarwal - Sorry for that. Please check now

Comment: Did that not work? If not, can you add a plunker or jsFiddle?

Comment: A plunker or jsFiddle will help, if you can create one.